# keras K.function error for layer output extraction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently have a modified resnet 50 architecture that takes two inputs. Building the model and training the model works fine, but when I’m trying to extract layer outputs using the backend function, I encounter errors.

I would prefer to extract layers using the backend function, rather than creating a new truncated model with just my layer of interest as the output.

The following snippet is self contained, and should be able to run and give the error I’ve been seeing.

I've tried reformatting the function in a few ways, such as  `K.function( [ mymodel.input[0],mymodel.input[1] ] ,  [mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6].output])`
or 
`K.function( [ mymodel.layers[0].input,mymodel.layers[1].input ] ,  [mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6].output])`
but nothing seems to fix the issue

```
##imports
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

#pop off the input
res = ResNet50(weights=None,include_top=True,classes=2)
res.layers.pop(0)

#add two inputs
auxinput= Input(batch_shape=(None,224,224,1), name='aux_input')
main_input = Input(batch_shape=(None,224,224,3), name='main_input')

#use a lambda functon to return just our main input (avoids errors from out auxilary input not being used in resnet50 component)
l_output = Lambda(lambda x: x[0])([main_input, auxinput])

#feed our main layer to resnet50
data_passed_thru = res(l_output)

#assemble the model with our two inputs, and output
mymodel = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxinput], outputs=[data_passed_thru])
mymodel.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss= keras.losses.poisson, metrics=[ 'accuracy'])
print("my model summary:")
mymodel.summary()

##generate some fake data for testing
fake_aux= np.zeros((224,224))
fake_aux=fake_aux[None,...]
fake_aux=fake_aux[...,None]
print('fake aux input shape:', fake_aux.shape)
fake_main= np.zeros((224,224,3))
fake_main=fake_main[None,...]
print('fake main input shape:', fake_main.shape)

#check our model inputs and target layer
print("inputs:", mymodel.input)
print("layer outout I'm trying to extract:", mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6])

#create function to feed inputs, get our desired layer outputs
get_output_func = K.function( mymodel.input ,  [mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6].output])

##this is the line that fails
X= [fake_main,fake_aux]
preds=get_output_func(X)
```

The error message I get is

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,224,224,3]
     [[{{node input_1}}]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by accessing the Resnet50 inputs directly for the function, rather than just the whole model's initial inputs. The K.function that works is

```
get_output_func = K.function( [mymodel.layers[-1].get_input_at(0)] ,  [mymodel.layers[-1].layers[-6].output])
X= [fake_main]
preds=get_output_func(X)
```

It only works because of my architecture only depends on the 1 input passing through, so not sure what the solution would be for other situations, but works for my case